# NameError: name '[string]' is not defined

Tags: python

When testing my program, I keep getting this error:

```
1. Encrypt a file
2. Decrypt a file
----> 1
Enter the filename you'd like to encrypt: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./encrypt.py", line 71, in <module>
    Main()
  File "./encrypt.py", line 58, in Main
    filename = input("Enter the filename you'd like to encrypt: ")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

And here is my code for the Main() function:

```
def Main():
        print("1. Encrypt a file")
        print("2. Decrypt a file")
        choice = str(input("----> "))
        if choice == '1':
                filename = input("Enter the filename you'd like to encrypt: ")
                password = input("Enter a password used for the encryption tool: ")
                encrypt(getKey(password), filename)
                print("File has been encrypted.")
        elif choice == '2':
                filename = input("Enter the filename you'd like to decrypt: ")
                password = input("Enter the password used for the encryption of this file: ")
                decrypt(getKey(password), filename)
                print("File has been decrypted. Note that if the password used in the encryption does " \
            + "not match the password you entered in, the file will remain encrypted.")
        else:
                print("Invalid option. Closing the program...")
```

I am using the simple input() method to get my data ('test', for example), and it keeps telling me whatever information I enter in at runtime, the name of what I just entered is not defined. I don't see any formatting errors, syntax errors, etc.

Comment: What python version is this?

Comment: I know that looks like a weird dupe but I strongly suspect you are using `input` instead of `raw_input` on Python 2 and the top answer there is the clearest explanation I can find.

Comment: Current version is 2.7.12

Answer (score 3):

You're going to want to use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`. `input` tries to run the expression it gets as a Python expression, whereas `raw_input` returns a string. This is in Python 2.x; in 3.x `raw_input` doesn't exist.

When you get the `NameError`, it's trying to run your input as an expression, but `test` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out my linux distro has both python 2.7.12 and python 3.5.2. Apparently the system defaults to python 2.7.12 instead of the newer version, so I fixed it by changing:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

> it keeps telling me whatever information I enter in at runtime, the name of what I just entered is not defined. I don't see any formatting errors, syntax errors, etc.

You are probably using Python 2.x. You should use: `raw_input(..)` instead of `input(..)`

Answer (score 0):

The `input` function treats whatever you input as a python expression. What you're looking for is the `raw_input` function which treats your input as a string.
Switch all your `input`s for `raw_input`s and you should be fine.